# Activity page tab selector font stays dark when active on Meta

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

The active tab in the profile page has a dark box around it and the font switches to white to allow reading the tab. However, the second set of tabs doesn't change font color and they're illegible. It happens for all tabs in that row: summary, answers, questions, etc. I'm running the latest version of Chrome on Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Design tag should get the design team a notification... I think.

Comment: When you mouse over the Tab, the text becomes visible.